# How to list two items from two different python lists as one item on a new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Could someone help me with the below? thank you in advance

```
list1 = ['123', '456', '789']
list2 = ['some text', 'some more text', 'additional string']

for x,y in zip(list1,list2):
    listFinal = [x+' ' + y for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

Currentresult:

```
['123 some text', '123 some more text', '123 additional string', '456 some text', '456 some more text', '456 additional string', '789 some text', '789 some more text', '789 additional string']
```

expectedResult:

```
['123 some text', '456 some more text', '789 additional string']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some functional utils:

```
listFinal = [*map(' '.join, zip(list1, list2))]
```

Docs on:

- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 2):

`listFinal = [x+' ' + y for x in list1 for y in list2]`

This makes the `zip()` function useless. You are iterating over the first list, then through the second list. This makes 3 copies of the element.

You can view it as follows:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        print(x+" "+y)
```

This is what the code is currently doing. Your `zip()` method was right.

You can do this instead.

```
list1 = ['123', '456', '789']
list2 = ['some text', 'some more text', 'additional string']
list3=[x + ' ' + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just do:

```
for i in range(0, len(list1) ):
    list1[i] += " " + list2[i]
```